# Visual Studio fica dando erro no projeto ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2012

Olá, estou tentando abrir um projeto ASP.NET MVC 5 e fica dando o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro]

Alguem pode me ajudar? Já instalei as atualizações e o MVC 5. Instalei o web pages através do NuGet: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor -Version 3.0.0

Comment: Você clicou no Yes, e ele baixou um pacote pra você?

Comment: Sim, eu fiz isso também!

Comment: Somente neste projeto ou em outros também? Já analisou o eventvwr do Windows?

Comment: Somente nesse projeto, lembrando que esse é o unico projeto MVC 5 que tenho aqui. Os outros funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Você pode abrir seu arquivo `.csproj` e colar o conteúdo dele aqui?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez excede limite de caracteres =X

Comment: Só preciso do que tem dentro de `<ProjectTypeGuids>`.

Comment: <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>

Comment: @f.fujihara Você por um acaso atualizou esse projeto pra MVC5 mas dentro do Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Visual Studio 2012, instale o seguinte pacote para poder ter suporte ao ASP.NET MVC5:

> https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WebNode11Pack.appids